# Is there a way to specify an invoice ID in Ripple URI?

Tags: transactions, ripple, bip21-uri

In Ripple [payment transactions](https://ripple.com/wiki/Transaction_Format#Payment_.280.29) we can specify an invoice ID that is used to make payments for a particular invoice. Is there a way to specify such an invoice ID in [Ripple's URI scheme](https://ripple.com/wiki/Ripple_URIs#send)?

Comment: I'm actually curious of this one myself.  After digging through the rippled code, I didn't readily see a way to do it.  I believe it might be a shared hash, so it could be originating from someone else.  Let me get out my Schwartz horn and see if we can call for help...

Comment: The InvoiceID can be anything at all that communicates to the recipient how the sender intended the payment to be applied. The Bitcoin outbound bridge uses it to [designate the Bitcoin address](https://ripple.com/wiki/Services_API#Payments) of the recipient. I don't know if the URI scheme offers a way to specify it though. If not, it should.

Comment: @ThePiachu thanks for adding a github issue. I'll add InvoiceID.

Comment: Although the original intent is otherwise, you may look also at the "DestinationTag" property.